# Check for unprotected (com.apple.m4v-video) M4V UTType?

Tags: ios, uttype

I am currently checking against certain UTTypes. For example I am able to test against the `public.mpeg-4` using `mpeg4Movie`.

```
if utType == .mpeg4Movie {
    ....
}
```

Which is true when `utType` is `public.mpeg-4`.

I want to do the same for unprotected m4v files.

When I look at the docs I only see the exact check for "protected" case:

```
/**
        An Apple protected MPEG-4 movie.

        **UTI:** com.apple.protected-mpeg-4-video

        **conforms to:** com.apple.m4v-video
    */
public static var appleProtectedMPEG4Video: UTType { get }
```

So if I do this:

```
if utType == .appleProtectedMPEG4Video {
    ....
}
```

It won't work, because the file is actually `com.apple.m4v-video` instead of `com.apple.protected-mpeg-4-video`.

So, how can I check for the `com.apple.m4v-video` case and not the `com.apple.protected-mpeg-4-video` using the provided apple constants?

Comment: Facing the same issue! Any known solutions?

Comment: @BadmintonCat I resorted to declare a static string `let m4vUnprotectedUTTypeIdentifier = "com.apple.m4v-video` and check against that. I did not find matching one from Apple to use for now.